# res.redirect() is not redirecting me to any page ,there are no errors ,can someone explain whats happening here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

Everything is working as expected but,
I wanted my user to shift to a different url as soon as he sends a message ,so I am trying to redirect him/her from the res variable in server after he sends a ajax post request to the server.
I am sure there is nothing wrong with client.js but res.redirect redirects me no where, I am on the same page, after the message has been sent.There are no errors . and both the console.log statements are being executed ,so something probably wrong with res.redirect ,please someone tell me what to do.

Basic Info:I am using express server, nodejs and javascript on client side.

**client.js**

```
$(document).ready(
    message=''
);
function getmessagefrominput(){
    var message =$('#message');
    var value = message.val();
    message.val('');
    return value;
}

function appendmessage(message){
    var messagecontainer =document.getElementById('messages');
    //console.log(messagecontainer);
    var mymessage= document.createElement("div")
    mymessage.setAttribute('class','sentmessagecontainer')
    var newmessage= document.createElement("p")
    newmessage.setAttribute('class','sent')
    newmessage.textContent=message;
    mymessage.appendChild(newmessage);
    messagecontainer.appendChild(mymessage);
}
function sendmessage(username,friend){
    var message=getmessagefrominput();
    //console.log('{from:'+username+',to:'+friend+',message:'+message+'}')
    if(message!=null && message!=''){        
        var jqxhr =$.post( "/ajax/newmessage", { from:username,to:friend,message:message } , ()=>{appendmessage(message);});
    }  
}
```

**server.js**

```
console.log('trying to redirect');
    res.redirect('/'+obj.from+'/direct/inbox/'+x);
    console.log('ok redrected')
```

;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do ajax, it launches a separate request to the server, which the redirect will not affect the main thread (page stays the same regardless the redirect on the ajax request).

If you want to redirect the page, you will either need to use `document.location.href` in your Ajax callback or request with `<form>`, which will replace your page with the request that can affect by redirection.

Comment: Okay so you are saying that I should redirect the user by changing the client side url,is there any way to do it using DOM

Comment: thanks so much this worked fro me,I did some search and then used `window.location.replace()` in client.js

Comment: is it not possible to change url from server side?